# save state of added widgets

Tags: jquery, gridster

How do I save the state of the added widget: Below is the function I'm using to add a widget on click of button:

```
 $('.js-resize-random').on('click', function() {
    gridster.add_widget('<li class="new">The new widget...</li>', 2, 1);
});
```

Here is the html:

```
<div>
<button class="js-resize-random">Add widget</button></div>
```

On refresh I need the added widget to retain its state. How do i do that?
Any ideas?????

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a directive recently for saving and loading the position of a widget of a dashboard. It's a simple attribute of the div of the widget.

```
appControl.directive('saveLoadGridsterPosition', ['whateverStoringDependency', function($whateverStoringDependency)
{
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var objectLoaded = whateverStoringDependency.load(attrs.saveLoadGridsterPosition);
        // Empty or errorous load
        if ((objectLoaded == undefined ) || (objectLoaded == null )) {
            console.log('Error loading ' + attrs.saveLoadGridsterPosition+'\'s position.');
        }
        else {
            // Here you set the row/col somewhere in the scope, for me its like scope.widget.row
            scope.widget.row = objectLoaded.row;
            scope.widget.col = objectLoaded.col;
        }

        var save = function() {
            // Here you should get the row/col from the scope
            var r = scope.widget.row;
            var c = scope.widget.col;
            var savingObject = {row: r, col: c};
            whateverStoringDependency.save(attrs.saveLoadGridsterPosition, savingObject);
        }

        scope.$on('$destroy', save);
    }
}]);
```

`'whateverStoringDependency'` can be a custom service that saves/loads stuff from local storage,  cookies, or session. And then I use it like this:

```
<div gridster="gridsterOpts">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="widget in widgets" gridster-item row="widget.row" col="widget.col" size-x="widget.sizeX" size-y="widget.sizeY">
            <div data-widget="widget" save-load-gridster-position="{{widget.name}}"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Maybe it's not nice, but for me it works perfectly. It also can do it on any angular event, like you define `"savePositions"` and listen for that instead of `"$destroy"`. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would say if you wanted  permanent change you might need to do something with Ajax to write the new markup into your database.

If it is more session specific you might address it with a cookie.

```
<?php
//check for cookie value
$widgetVar =  $_COOKIE['widgetStatus']; 
?>

<?php if($widgetVar!='true'): ?>
$('.js-resize-random').on('click', function() {
    gridster.add_widget('<li class="new">The new widget...</li>', 2, 1);
    //code to set the cookie once the button is clicked
    document.cookie = "widgetStatus=true";

});
<?php else: ?>

    This markup renders if the cookie is true when the page loads. So this is where the widget would go.

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I need to get the id of the widget that i added to get the 'widgetStatus'? If so how do i do that?? Also FYI: I'm using jquery-gridster for this.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are saying there may be different widgets so you need the code to detect which ones are present?  Perhaps then 'widgetStatus' should be a comma delineated string of IDs rather than a simple Boolean? You can parse the string into an array and check via PHP or JS.